# is there any function or suggestion to split list into sublist

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap, maps

I'm trying to solve the following problem

I have 3 lists

```
A {1.2.3.4.5} 
B {6,7}
C {8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
```

and limit is 4 (configurable)
then the output should be such that the lists are splitted to not have more than 4 elements put together
the list elements are put in sub list based on their list number with limit of 4 elements.

output for above example :

1. A{1,2,3,4} , B{} , C{}
2. A{5} , B{6,7} , C{8}
3. A{} , B{} , C{9,10,11,12}
4. A{} , B{} , C{13,14,15}

I have tried below code to split the list

I am getting the output
[1, 2, 3, 4][][]
I cant move forward for the next list. Does anyone have suggestions.
I know i have very bad programming skill. Please help.

```
public void listDivider() {
    ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> al2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> al3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    al1.add("1");
    al1.add("2");
    al1.add("3");
    al1.add("4");
    al1.add("5");
    System.out.println("List 1>" + al1);
    al2.add("6");
    al2.add("7");
    System.out.println("List 2>" + al2);
    al3.add("8");
    al3.add("9");
    al3.add("10");
    al3.add("11");
    al3.add("12");
    al3.add("13");
    al3.add("14");
    al3.add("15");
    float batchSize = 4;
    float totalListElements = Math.round((al1.size() + al2.size() + al3.size()) / batchSize);
    LinkedList<String> allElements = new LinkedList<String>();
    allElements.addAll(al1);
    allElements.add("|");
    allElements.addAll(al2);
    allElements.add("|");
    allElements.addAll(al3);
    ArrayList<String> added1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> added2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> added3 = new ArrayList<>();
    int position = 0;
    int count = 0;    
    for (int i = 0; i < allElements.size(); i++) {
        String check = allElements.get(i);
        if (check.equals("|")) {
            position++;    
        }
        if (count <= 4) {
            if (position == 1) {
                if (count == 4) {
                    count = 0;
                    System.out.print(added1);
                    System.out.print(added2);
                    System.out.print(added3);
                    added1.clear();
                    added2.clear();
                    added3.clear();
                    break;
                }  
                added1.add(allElements.removeFirst());
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n"+allElements);
}
```

Comment: This question might be being downvoted because it's hard to understand what your program is supposed to do. Can you describe in more detail how the input should be transformed into the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
static void splitBatch(int batchSize, List<String>...lists) {
    int length = lists.length;
    int[] indexes = new int[length];
    int total = 0;
    for (List<String> list : lists)
        total += list.size();
    int selected = 0;
    List<List<String>> batch = new ArrayList<>();
    while (selected < total) {
        batch.clear();
        int count = batchSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            int index = indexes[i];
            int size = lists[i].size();
            int subSize = Math.min(count, Math.min(batchSize, size - index));
            List<String> sublist = lists[i].subList(index, index + subSize);
            batch.add(sublist);
            indexes[i] += subSize;
            count -= subSize;
            selected += subSize;
        }
        System.out.println(batch);
    }
}
```

and

```
List<String> a = List.of("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
List<String> b = List.of("6", "7");
List<String> c = List.of("8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15");
splitBatch(4, a, b, c);
```

output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [], []]
[[5], [6, 7], [8]]
[[], [], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
[[], [], [13, 14, 15]]
```

If you have four lists and batch size is 6.

```
List<String> a = List.of("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
List<String> b = List.of("6", "7");
List<String> c = List.of("8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15");
List<String> d = List.of("16", "17", "18");
splitBatch(6, a, b, c, d);
```

output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6], [], []]
[[], [7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12], []]
[[], [], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]]
```